# Toast Notification in Windows Service Win10

Tags: c++, windows-10, windows-services, localnotification

Im developing a software and im considering it as a Service because i need it to listen to ports 24X7 and notify when new client got connected(Toast Notification). I was able to send Toast notification from classic Win32 c++ application but i can't send it through Windows Service even when i check 'Allow Service to Interact with UI'. What do you think about the software Architecture?! Do you think i should reconsider the software Architecture or there is any other way to send Toast notification through Windows Service?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Allow Service to Interact with UI" only has an effect until XP.  Up to then, the first user logged in runs in Session 0, the same Session that services run in.  But from Vista onwards, Session 0 is now isolated, users run in Session 1 and higher only, so services can no longer interact with users.

When you want your service to display a toast, have the service use `CreateProcessAsUser()` to spawn a separate process in an available user Session (plenty of examples floating around demonstrating how to do that), and then that process can display the toast as needed.